# VB script not returning any value

Tags: datetime, vbscript

```
Function NextMonthName(dateval)
    Dim tmp : tmp = DateAdd("m", 1, dateval)
    NextMonthName = MonthName(Month(tmp))
    return NextMonthName
    Wscript.Echo  NextMonthName 
    End Function

Function PrevMonthName(dateval)
    Dim tmp : tmp = DateAdd("m", -1, dateval)
    NextMonthName = MonthName(Month(tmp))
    return NextMonthName 
    End Function
```

I am running the above mentioned VB script and it completes fine without any output. I want the result in text file. I am not able to get the output in console also.

Comment: How are you calling these?

Comment: Call NextMonthName(07/15/2015)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no `return` in VBScript, this

```
Option Explicit

Function NextMonthName(dateval)
    Dim tmp : tmp = DateAdd("m", 1, dateval)
    NextMonthName = MonthName(Month(tmp))
    return NextMonthName
End Function

WScript.Echo NextMonthName(Now)
```

will fail with

```
...\31436343.vbs(6, 5) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Variable is undefined: 'return'
```

(looks like you asked a question based on code containing a global "On Error Resume Next")

Removing the offending line -

```
Option Explicit

Function NextMonthName(dateval)
    Dim tmp : tmp = DateAdd("m", 1, dateval)
    NextMonthName = MonthName(Month(tmp))
End Function

WScript.Echo NextMonthName(Now)
```

solves the problem:

```
cscript 31436343.vbs
August
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the issue and iam getting output. But I want the output format to be something like Aug 2015 rather than August. and write this output to text file

Comment: @ajayk - Obviously, these new problems/specs are **not** covered by your question 'VB script not returning any value'. So create **two** new questions, showing at least some effort at solving those problems.

Answer (score 0):

To write the ouput into text file ;

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title,dateval,Message
Title = "The previous Month and The Next Month" 
dateval = Now()
Message = "The previous Month : "& PrevMonthName(dateval) & " "& Year(dateval) & vbCrLf &_
 "The Next Month   :"& NextMonthName(dateval) & " "& Year(dateval)
 MsgBox Message,VbInformation,Title
 WriteLog Message
'*******************************************
Function PrevMonthName(dateval)
    Dim tmp : tmp = DateAdd("m", -1, dateval)
    PrevMonthName = MonthName(Month(tmp))   
End Function
'*******************************************
Function NextMonthName(dateval)
    Dim tmp : tmp = DateAdd("m", 1, dateval)
    NextMonthName = MonthName(Month(tmp))
End Function
'*******************************************
Sub WriteLog(strText)
    Dim fs,ts,LogFile
    Const ForWriting = 2
    LogFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName, InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "log"
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(LogFile,ForWriting,True)
    ts.WriteLine strText
    ts.Close
End Sub
'********************************************
```

Comment: Thank you so much Hackoo. just what I was expecting .Perfect!!! Thank you so much. Iam in learning stage and will pick up from here.

Comment: @ajayk in this case don't forget to mark this answer as "accepted" and welcome on stackoverflow and take a look at this to undestand how SO works ==> http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: End Function
'*******************************************
Function CurrMonthName(dateval)
    Dim tmp : tmp = DateAdd("m", 0, dateval)
      CurrMonthName = MonthName(Month(tmp))
  CurrMonthName = replace(CurrMonthName , "%M",CurrMonthName)
iam trying to format the month name so that it displays first 3 letters. On searching found %M can be used. I tried using it in above code and results are not coming as expected. It is still displaying full month

Comment: This is another question you should accept it as answer and ask a new question and post what code did you tried in your new question

Comment: sure posted as new question